# Confusion on using eventbrite API

Tags: javascript, html, api, curl, eventbrite

I am currently self learning coding and I was trying to learn using Eventbrite API. I have used google map's API before and some others but while using this one, I was really confused. Could someone please guide me a little?

I'm trying to make a simple site where I can have a form for someone to create an event.

This is what eventbrite docs are saying to use

```
curl -X POST   https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/{organization_id}/events/   -H 'Authorization: Bearer PERSONAL_OAUTH_TOKEN'   -H "Accept: application/json"
  -d '{
        "event": {
            "name": {
                "html": "My New Event"
            },
            "start":{
                "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
                "utc": "2019-12-01T02:00:00Z"
            },
            "end":{
                "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
                "utc": "2019-12-01T05:00:00Z"
            },
            "currency": "USD"
        }
    }'
```

But honestly I'm not really sure what curl is. I tried googling and reading all the eventbrite docs and it seemed like cURL but I wasn't too sure how to implement that onto my html page?

And then I'm supposed to get an event ID from that and implement it to make a ticket class?

```
curl -X POST   https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/{event_id}/ticket_classes/   -H 'Authorization: Bearer PERSONAL_OAUTH_TOKEN'   -H "Accept: application/json"
  -d '{
        "ticket_class": {
            "name": "VIP",
            "quantity_total": 100,
            "cost": "USD,1000"
            }
        }'
```

Comment: `curl` is a well known command line HTTP client.  Its invocation is often used, as it is here, to exemplify appropriate request url pattern, method, headers, and payload format, without exposing the reader to the intricacies of a programming language.  LIkely, outside the scope of your selection, the eventbrite documentation also shows the response payload as well, which will show you how you can get the event ID from the first call and use it in the `{event_id}` field of the second call.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, `curl` is a well-known tool (and library) commonly used for examples in API calls.

Eventbrite's API reference is very complete. You didn't mention exactly which language you want, but I'll post an example for javascript since it's in your posts' tags

1. Go to
   https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event/create/create-an-event?console=1
2. On the right side, choose "Show example"
3. A dropdown box indicating "RAW" will show up. Click it and select "Javascript".

A working code example will be shown. You can even run it right from your browser. Notice that you need a valid login before creating an event.